# Convert (heavily formula-loaded) Excel spreadsheet to user-friendly web calculator

Tags: javascript, excel, forms, excel-formula, calculator

I need to create a webtool that takes several input values and generates a number of outputs based on complex sequences of arithmetic calculations in an Excel workbook. I am thinking of hard-coding the formulas into Javascript and creating a live-update user input form, but I don't want to waste my time if there is a more efficient way of doing this...I have heard of embedding live spreadsheets in webpages but realize this is only compatible with IE, which is not preferable. Does anyone have suggestions to help get me started?

Comment: Honestly, your best option is to try either [Google Spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/?pli=1#home) or just embedding them. Reproducing Excel output dynamically through JavaScript formulas sounds extremely difficult -- about as difficult as building Excel. Embedding live spreadsheets shouldn't be frowned upon either, as I'm sure users don't mind switching to IE for a specific task like this one (unless cross-OS is one of your concerns), and most have something like IE Tab installed.

Comment: what are you doing with all of this? If you want to reference the data later, a database makes sense in this situation. You can pretty easily use forms to generate reports and excel files using what you mention, and a database will let you create dynamic reporting to excel, if you care to go beyond a onetime excel output.

Comment: @datatoo: Yes, I would love for the user to be able to download and save the results in an excel file, then be able to compare various results using different inputs. These results will only be for the user's purpose though; I don't need them saved or anything. Would you still recommend a database? If so, sorry for being a noob but how would I get started with that?

Comment: it sounds like you want to be able to generate multiple results based on differing inputs. Do you want to offer all results on a single sheet for comparison, or multiple sheets for their comparison and consumption? Are static results acceptable, or do you want formulas? Would it be acceptable to generate on screen what they want, and download the result. Does it need to be excel on the user end for any further data entry or just a simple way to view later? How big is the data being output? tens, hundreds, thousands of rows? A database might not be necessary, but would handle calculations

Comment: The final output is ultimately about 40 values but there are a bunch of intermediate values on different sheets that would be nice for the user to see as well. I was thinking the formulas would be accessible in Excel; otherwise they would appear upon a mouse rollover event. Also, I don't know how hard this would be, but there are 6 prototypes generated by the workbook I would like the user to be able to mix and match using different percentages of the output values. A single downloadable workbook for each time the form is filled out would be great. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Would a database be necessary to generate an excel file with the formulas included?

Answer (score 2):

You would need more than javascript to accomplish this. Despite the web guru naysayers, I made it work. You need IIS and Excel on the server. People are getting hung up on the 2nd requirement, but you have to use what is available. SpreadSheet Gear is an alternative.

But the first question you should ask yourself, *do you really need a web front-end*? I would explore building your front-end in excel; having a cell mapping tab that maps your UI elements to the cells of your calculator spreadsheet and have a macro copy/paste the contents from one spreadsheet to another.

The beauty of this set-up is you can run batch through your calculator spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Formula.js](http://www.stoic.com/pages/formula), which is a JavaScript implementation of Excel's formula functions.